# Unable to remove the page outer margin of the pdf which is created using html/css in flutter iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, flutter, pdf-generation

I am trying to remove the outer white margin of PDF which is created using Html/css in flutter-iOS-app. **In case of android the layout is working fine** but incase of iOS there is left-margin issue as shown in the attachment of iOS.

**Issue at Github using DartPdf:** [Issue at DartPdf](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/135)

**Issue at Github using flutter_html_to_pdf:** [Issue at flutter_html_to_pdf](https://github.com/Afur/flutter_html_to_pdf/issues/17)

I have used these libraries in order to convert and render html to pdf.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  pdf: ^1.3.17
  printing: ^2.0.0
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.4
```

**Method to print html as PDF:**

```
Future<void> printPdfMethod() async {
  print('Print ...');
  await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
    return await Printing.convertHtml(
        format: PdfPageFormat.a4
            .applyMargin(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
        html:
            '<?xml version="1.0"?> <html> <head> <title>CSS Template</title> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <style> @page { size: A4; margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; padding:0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; } body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: static; width:100%; height:100%; } </style> </head> <body style="margin:0;padding:10" bgcolor="#144434"> <h1 style="color:white">Test Layout Margin</h1></body> </html>');
  });
}
```

**style-property:** Using this property the margin issue *resolves in android but still not working on iOS case*.

```
@page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
    }

body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

**Android Screenshot:**

[image]

**iOS Screenshot:**

[image]

**Required Result:**
The pdf will only contain the dark green layout and remove that outer white spacing in both iOS and android.

**Note(When 2 or more pages):** Incase of iOS when using this format property (format: PdfPageFormat.a4
            .applyMargin(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0)), when the PDF splits the some of the views or data are invisible or hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Finally this will resolve the issue of printing:**

We have to set the margin using copyWith(..). applyMargin(..) will only increase the margin from what you already have. And you also have to use the provided paper format:

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
  return await Printing.convertHtml(
      format: format.copyWith(marginLeft: 0, marginTop: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0),
      html: '<?xml version="1.0"?><html><body style="margin:0;padding:0" bgcolor="#144434"><h1 style="color:white">Test Layout Margin</h1></body></html>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**css**

```
@media print {
  body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    border:0 !important;
    outline:0 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: pls share live link .. i will check and let you know

Comment: I have already mentioned the code in above section. It works only on web but not in iOS app. You can try above code in your simulator. Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look at another answer which I have mentioned. This answer is given by @dav who is the creator of dart_pdf library. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write This code at the top of your page

```
@page {
  margin: 0cm 0cm;
  padding: 0cm 0cm;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0cm;
  padding-top: 0cm;
  margin-left: 1.2cm;
  margin-right: 1.2cm;
  margin-bottom: 1.2cm;
}
```